# How to extract time series json data from spark dataframe using groupby

Tags: json, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, time-series

I have the following data in a spark dataframe:

| id | series |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"2016-01-31T00:00:00.000Z": null, "2016-06-30T00:00:00.000Z": 6394317.0, "2016-07-31T00:00:00.000Z": 6550781.0, "2016-08-31T00:00:00.000Z": 7107308.0} |
| 2 | {"2016-01-31T00:00:00.000Z": null, "2016-06-30T00:00:00.000Z": 6394317.0} |

I would like to extract the time series data into a format more suitable to work; e.g. the following format

| id | timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "2016-01-31T00:00:00.000Z" | 2000.3 |
| 1 | "2016-02-31T00:00:00.000Z" | 100000.3 |
| 1 | "2016-02-31T00:00:00.000Z" | null |
| 2 | "2012-01-31T00:00:00.000Z" | 6394317.0 |
| 2 | "2013-02-31T00:00:00.000Z" | 10000317.0 |

I have tried df.groupby('id') and can achieve this in pandas by iterating over the groupby object. e.g:

```
for fund_id, df_i in df.groupby('id'):

        ts = json.loads(df_i['series'].iloc[0]) # get time series
        id = df_i['id'].iloc[0] # get id

        # storing all timeseries in temp df
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','date','value'])
        df_temp['value']=ts.values()
        df_temp['date']=ts.keys()
        df_temp['id'] = id

        # Finally append all df_temp
```

Any ideas how to do the same thing in spark?

Comment: Can you include the schema of the DataFrame in your question? `df.printSchema()` likely.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski   `root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- series: string (nullable = true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, yes. You have to jump through some hoops to convert the json string to an array, explode it, then split the remaining string only on the colon (:) outside the quotes.

Sorry, can't read. Pyspark approach:

```
jstring = """{"2016-01-31T00:00:00.000Z": null, "2016-06-30T00:00:00.000Z": 6394317.0, "2016-07-31T00:00:00.000Z": 6550781.0, "2016-08-31T00:00:00.000Z": 7107308.0}"""
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, jstring)
    ],
    ["id", "series"] 
    
)

from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace,explode,split,trim,expr

df.select("id",regexp_replace(regexp_replace("series","\\{",""),"\\}", "").alias("s")). \
select("id",explode(split("s",",").cast("array<string>")).alias("exp_series")). \
select("id",split("exp_series",":(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)").alias("foo")). \
select("id",trim(expr("foo[0]")).alias("a"),trim(expr("foo[1]")).alias("b")).show()
```

Scala approach:

```
 scala> val jstring = """{"2016-01-31T00:00:00.000Z": null, "2016-06-30T00:00:00.000Z": 6394317.0, "2016-07-31T00:00:00.000Z": 6550781.0, "2016-08-31T00:00:00.000Z": 7107308.0}"""
    jstring: String = {"2016-01-31T00:00:00.000Z": null, "2016-06-30T00:00:00.000Z": 6394317.0, "2016-07-31T00:00:00.000Z": 6550781.0, "2016-08-31T00:00:00.000Z": 7107308.0}

     scala> val data = Seq((1,jstring))
        data: Seq[(Int, String)] = List((1,{"2016-01-31T00:00:00.000Z": null, "2016-06-30T00:00:00.000Z": 6394317.0, "2016-07-31T00:00:00.000Z": 6550781.0, "2016-08-31T00:00:00.000Z": 7107308.0}))
        
        scala> val df = data.toDF("id","series")
        df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, series: string]
        
        scala> df.select($"id",regexp_replace(regexp_replace($"series","\\{",""),"\\}", "").alias("s")).
             | select($"id",explode(split($"s",",").cast("array<string>")).alias("exp_series")).
             | select($"id",split($"exp_series",":(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)").alias("foo")).
             | select($"id",trim($"foo".getItem(0)).alias("a"),trim($"foo".getItem(1)).alias("b")).show(false)
        +---+--------------------------+---------+
        |id |a                         |b        |
        +---+--------------------------+---------+
        |1  |"2016-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"|null     |
        |1  |"2016-06-30T00:00:00.000Z"|6394317.0|
        |1  |"2016-07-31T00:00:00.000Z"|6550781.0|
        |1  |"2016-08-31T00:00:00.000Z"|7107308.0|
        +---+--------------------------+---------+
```